# React component updating/rendering - componentDidUpdate NOT called

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react component which is connected to a parent container. The container has mapStateToProps. I have a console log in the container. The props are updating. I can SEE the prop updating in the component/child.

componentDidUpdate is not being called. I have no idea how a render could possibly be called without componentDidUpdate being called. But that is happening. I see the component update on my screen, I have the props console.logged and they are updating. But componentDidUpdate is not. I feel like I'm crazy.

Has anyone experienced this before??

Comment: Could you include this component code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into something similar now. Wondering if my component is unmounting/remounting, which would cause render without calling `componentDidUpdate`, right?

UPDATE: Yep, my component was unmounting/remounting because a parent component was responding to the change in redux state by no longer rendering my component. Can't call `componentDidUpdate` if I don't exist, and won't call `componentDidUpdate` if I'm mounting!

Comment: For those experiencing the same, `componentDidMount()` is one option to explore.